# Dynamically change config colors.js in React Native using state/context

Tags: react-native, react-context

I have a simple Colors file in my RN project that looks like this:

```
export default {
    color: '#2e66f5',
    dark1: '#232a3a',
    dark2: '#141c2b',
    white1: '#fff',
    white2: '#fff',
    aqua: '#3ecac1',
    green: '#d5d841', 
    yellow: '#f3c51e',
    red: '#ff3235'
}
```

It is being used everywhere throughout my app.

All i am trying to do is use context/state to dynamically change the props of color, dark1, dark2, etc using state. The issue is that i would normally import useContext and do

```
const {activeColor} = useContext(AppContext)

export default {
    color: activeColor,
    //etc
}
```

and set the activeColor state anywhere in the app. But since Colors.js is not a react component i cannot use context/state inside this file.

Answer (score 0):

The React page shows a good example of how to use `useContext` React Hook:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

ContextHolder.ts

```
const colors = {
  ....
}
function updateContext(attr)
{
  colors: attr,
}
const contextToUse = {
  colors: colors,
  updateContext: updateContext,
}
export default contextToUse;
```

File 2:

```
import contextToUse from "../ContextHolder.ts";
const context = createContext(contextToUse);
```

Then call updateContext

```
context.updateContext({dark1: "#3A3A3A"});
```

Comment: this is not at all what i want to do. If you read and understand my post, i am trying to CHANGE the value of colors object using the context api not the other way around!

Comment: It is difficult to understand the post as your phrasing is very confusing. Please reword with what you have stated in your comment.

Comment: its pretty obvious and clear what i need to do...i very simply want to change the value of  color: '#2e66f5', to color: 'red'. (in the colors.js file) how can i do that? (dynamically of course)

Comment: Updated post. `color`, `dark1`, `dark2` are not props as they are not passed into an element or component. They are attributes of the context object. A more clear, in my opinion, way of stating it would be you want to update the context object attributes using the context hook.

Comment: that's more what i was trying to achieve, i will try this, thanks

Comment: why are you importing this file and what is inside it?
import contextToUse from "../ContextHolder.ts"

Comment: They are two seperate files seperated at the import statement. Updated post.

Comment: in file 2, did you mean to write: const context = createContext(contextToUse) ?